# Cell Fracture Causing Squares

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

I am trying to use the cell fracture addon to make tiny, pointy shards from a plane. I will have objects flying through the ground and shattering it. The original plane looks like ice when it is textured. When I turn the quantity up in the cell fracture settings, the pieces look like rectangles. Like I stated I wanted to make many tiny, uneven, pointy shards. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Increase the noise amount to 1. If you want the fractures much like splinter you can under Scale increase the scale for the first one (x-axis)

Comment: thanks, @vadar but how would i make really small pieces. The new pieces are rather large.

Comment: increase the count, known as Source Limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to modify certain parameters of the cell fracture tool. To change the numbers of fractures increase the Source Limit. To avoid all fractures looking like squares increase the noise. I would increase is all the way to `1`, this will look the most natural.

[image]